# AccelerationSensor.accelerationchanged() making app slow

Tags: android, crash, accelerometer, android-sensors

in my app, i use the AccelerationSensor.accelerationchanged(xAccel, yAccel, zAccel) API
the problem is the method is called every o.oooo1 change in any axis, so the app becomes very slow, some times even becomes "non-responding"

Is there a way to check if the integer part has changed and let away any decimal change?

Comment: What sensor polling interval are you using?

Comment: sensor polling interval: 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I am doing, in my `onStartCommand()` of my service

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

This is the function I am handling my data, it is pretty light weight but it should give you an idea using a threshold. In my case I really just need to know the device a bit, in my case it turned out the differenceValue neeeded to be about 1.75G but it might be different for you.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


    if(last[0] == 0.0f &&
       last[1] == 0.0f &&
       last[2] == 0.0f){

        last[0] = event.values[0];
        last[1] = event.values[1];
        last[2] = event.values[2];

        return;
    }

    float diff = 0f;

    if(Math.abs(last[0] - event.values[0]) > differenceValue ||
       Math.abs(last[1] - event.values[1]) > differenceValue ||
           Math.abs(last[2] - event.values[2]) > differenceValue){

        Log.d(TAG,"G values are "+event.values[0]+" "+event.values[1]+" "+event.values[2]);
        Log.d(TAG,"Last G values are "+last[0]+" "+last[1]+" "+last[2]);



        diff = Math.abs(last[0] - event.values[0]);

        if(diff < Math.abs(last[1] - event.values[1])){
           diff = Math.abs(last[1] - event.values[1]);
        }

        if(diff < Math.abs(last[2] - event.values[2])){
           diff = Math.abs(last[2] - event.values[2]);
        }

        Log.d(TAG,"Sensor difference: "+diff);

        //Do what ever processing you need here

    }

    last[0] = event.values[0];
    last[1] = event.values[1];
    last[2] = event.values[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you register a listener for a sensor it allows you to set a frequency.  Use a slower frequency.

Comment: Also you might want to have a threshold value that if the difference is less something just return and don't do you process of the values.

Comment: still no use, i went from 400 to 700

Comment: Then the threshold is the way to go, as draksia suggested.  You must be doing some heavy processing for that to make the app go unresponsive.  Maybe you should fire off a thread to do the actual calculations.